# Horizontal scrolling needed as in the link

Tags: javascript, html

I had been trying to implement horizontal sliding as in [this link](http://1uphost.in/des2/dreamsol/over2cloud/html/) provided. I in fact have used vertical scolling as in this link. I want the same to appear horizontally. Any suggestions? [website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nauNN.png)

As in the image, I want the page to slide to the left as any of the tiles in the top is clicked and so forth.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
        $items.mouseover(function() {
            $items.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            var index = $items.index($(this));
            $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
        }).eq(0).mouseover();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the width of the body equal to number of sections times width of each section. (should be equal widths). For example, you have 5 sections, each with a width of 4000px. Therefore body should be 4000 * 5, 20000px. Then float each section left, and hide horizontal scrollbar.

**tutorial: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/**

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LYxQ7/**

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks its working. but is there any way to get away with the scroller??? i tried overflow:hidden but to no avail...